# Insulation between floors?

Tags: insulation

I’m currently renovating the second floor of my 1950’s 2-story Cape. For context, I’m located in Massachusetts. The entire roof and gable walls down to the soffits will be getting spray foamed. The first floor has base-board heat and the second floor will be getting electric heat-pumps. Is there any reason to maintain or upgrade the tattered old fiberglass batt insulation between the floor joists? Will climate or sound dampening be affected with or without the insulation? I don’t intend to spend a fortune in rock wool or anything but would be interested in sound travel mitigation. There will be approximately 1.25” subfloor and padded carpet upon completion. Any input Is appreciated. TIA

Comment: Padded carpet will probably do more to lessen sound travel than insulation.  Why not go completely heat pump/s instead of only half?  Electric heat is hard on your electric bill.

Answer (score 2):

That insulation is not needed and serves little purpose for energy conservation as both floors are going to be conditioned.

It also doesn't do much for sound deadening as the sound is carried through the joists also.  Also, most new houses do not have any insulation between habitted floors.

Comment: For serious sound isolation you'd want to consider a sprung ceiling, to decouple it from the joists. And other tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question: "...Is there any reason to maintain or upgrade the tattered old fiberglass batt insulation between the floor joists? Will climate or sound dampening be affected with or without the insulation? "

It will not hurt anything leaving it.

You will save time and mess leaving it.

It will help with sound deadening more than not having it there.

It will cost you nothing to leave it.

I think the answer is evident.